# Multiple MongoDB database Connections in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have always created a single connection with one connection string. My question is, how to make multiple connections(MongoDB instances) if an array of connection strings are given in NodeJs get API?

Let’s say multiple connection strings will have the same type of database. e.g., my database name is “University” and this database is available in all different locations. And I wanted to write one common API which will provide me with an array of universities from different connections, how to do it?

Example

```js
connectionString1 = mongodb://localhost:27017
connectionString2 = mongodb://localhost:27018
connectionString3 = mongodb://localhost:27019
```

Now I wanted to connect with all three connection strings and fetch all records from them and send them
in response to one common API, how can I do it in an efficient manner? Also after retrieval of each query, I need to close the corresponding database instances.

Your input will help me to understand this structure in a better way

Comment: is the array of connection strings a result of you running a sharded cluster?

Comment: @GregBrodzik No these are not shards. These are simple connection strings to connect different databases. You can think of accessing replicas but these are not. Just separate database instances which have the same collections where I want to read and write simultaneously.

Comment: ok so no replica set, and these "same type of database[s]" are sitting on the same server? in that case I'm assuming you've name-spaced the db "University" you note (imagine a collision if not). and to confirm you intend to query (perhaps merge?) results from across all these databases of the same type (I believe that's what you suggest). a little background on why you have topology configured this way could help, I might be missing something

Comment: @GregBrodzik you are correct. "same type of database[s]". Let's say from all databases I get a list of universities and I wanted to combine the results of those into one array and create one API response. E.g., db1 returns "A, B" and db2 returns "C, D", so I wanted to combine "A","B","C","D" all four objects into one API. I know I have to create promises in Node but after everything is resolved then only I wanted to send a response from that API. In my case, I am able to send only "A","B" and "C","D" separately. Not combined into single API

Comment: I'm not super well versed in Node, but in Django for an exact situation like this, I simply define the DB to use via the URL route...maybe this works for you? For instance... example.com/db_to_use/[api_request]

Comment: @ViaTech Can you please provide a detailed solution?

Comment: @Prasanna, in Django that is super easy, it is a router implementation, in node ill have to look depending on whichever framework you use. How do you define your routes? If you share that code, I can probably piece together an example

Answer (score 0):

Execute your query against each database using example function named `exec`, and await the returned promise array by `Promise.allSettled`. Once settled, parse (e.g., reduce, maybe sort) for proper merging.

```
// each db with client.db(name)
const dbArr = [db1, db2, ...];

// execute query for given collection across each db, return promise array
function exec(coll, query) {
    let p = [];
    for (let db of dbArr) {
       p.push(db.collection(coll).find(query))
    }
    return p;
}

// main
async function fetchUniversitiesBy(filter) {
    try {
   // make mongo filter doc
   const query = filter
 
   const results = await Promise.allSettled(exec('university', query));

   /* 
    reduce, or execute any other manipulation here to merge results. 
    Can check `status` of settled objects here 
   */
   return results.reduce((acc, c) => [...acc, ...c], []);
   } catch(e) {
     console.log(e)
   } finally {
      // client `close()` here
   }
}
```

In terms of 'API', invoke `fetchUniversitiesBy` where you defined your `api/universities/get` (or however defined) route. Imagine your request params can be passed as `filter`.

Comment: This is a good solution, but if any of the promises rejects then it will not work

Comment: updated to use `allSettled` ("...[a]synchronously fulfilled, when all promise in the given iterable have settled (either fulfilled or rejected)").